Movie about a man who doesn't know to fight and gets trained by someone then he ends up in prison
I didn't watch the whole movie only parts of it. He are some of the instances I remembered,
The hero guy doesn't knows to fight so he hires someone who teaches him fighting, later on that guy fucks hero's wife (I'm not so sure on this). Later he kills someone and ends up in prison. He is now a trained fighter or something, once during a time he fights a giant black person and he knocks him out. Also they make some racist joke to which he says "Didn't you watch the Geographic program, which says we all come from Africa and we are all the same." (I don't fully remember what he said). I think this a comedy film. 

It's Big Stan, a 2007 comedy with Rob Schneider, but he's not jailed for murder.

A weak con man panics when he learns he's going to prison for fraud. He hires a mysterious martial arts guru who helps transform him into a martial arts expert who can fight off inmates who want to hurt or love him. 

And at a certain point Stan says to the huge black prisoner:

Didn't you see that Nova episode? They did that DNA test. We all come from Africa!

Here's the trailer:




This was the movie! Thank you!
